# Browser automatically inserts unwanted code on enter in contenteditable div

Tags: html, css, browser, contenteditable

I've got a contenteditable div with an ul and some li's in it. Now if I want to add some more text behind the list, I place the cursor after the last li ("3") and hit enter twice. After the first enter it adds a new li and after the second enter it closes the ul and adds a div with a br inside it so that I can start to write in it. ([Example #1](http://jsfiddle.net/8wfss/))

**Expected code:**

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<p>Test</p>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul><div><br></div>
</div>
```

This is the expected behaviour. But if there are some stylesheets defined for the li's the browser doesn't only add a new div with br but it also adds different code according to the styles you have defined ([Example #2](http://jsfiddle.net/7hWRY/1/)).

**Resulting code:**

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<p>Test</p>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul><div><font face="Arial"><span style="line-height: 20px;"><br></span></font></div>
</div>
```

What can I do to prevent this browser behaviour? I do want to have some stylesheets for the li's but I don't want the browser to insert whatever it likes in my html code.

Comment: What exactly did you type and which browser are you testing on? When I do that in Firefox (click after the 3, 2x enter to break out of the list, type text), I get `<li>3</li></ul><p>text<br></p><ul> </ul>` that is, a `p` without styles and an extra `ul`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that... The problem occures in Chrome 29.
Click after the 3, 2x enter and you'll get the "Resulting code" I wrote above.

Comment: So it's different per browser. Then I don't know if there's something you can do. You could always write a Javascript routine that checks if there are `<font>` elements present, or empty `<ul>` elements in the case of Firefox, but that feels like a patch, not a real solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of bigger sets of Blink's and Webkit's (Chrome, Opera, Safari) bugs. On CKEditor's dev site there's a [ticket grouping some of them](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9998) and I reported it also on Blink's and Webkit's sites:

- ​http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226941
- ​https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114791

but no one responded... ;/

As was said, there are only two ways to get rid of this problem:

- write your own backspace, delete and enter keys support (very complicated),
- don't use any styling (very uncool).

So I'm afraid that there's no other option currently than reminding Blink and Webkit teams that their engines should not produce this crappy HTML.

Comment: I just found an article on [Working around Chrome's contenteditable span bug](http://www.neotericdesign.com/blog/2013/3/working-around-chrome-s-contenteditable-span-bug) which might be helpful.