# document.execCommand not obeying CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `contentEditable` `<div>` which I'm turning into a very simple text editor. When 'tab' is pressed, a bullet point is created using `document.execCommand('insertUnorderedList');` which works great. Here's the problem though:

HTML:

```
<div id="wysiwyg">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wysiwyg{
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: rgb(70,70,70);
}

#wysiwyg ul li {
    font-family: 'Calendas Regular', serif !important;
    font-size: 1em; 
}
```

When I create a bullet point using the `document.execCommand('insertUnorderedList');` though, it gets styled as if it were just any old text inside my `#wysiwyg`, not as if it were a bullet point, but if I insert some initial text (via HTML, not via using the contentEditable-ness) in the `#wysiwyg` then it styles bullet points correctly.

Any ideas what's up?

Thanks

Comment: I am testing this on Safari, and for some reason, the browser inserts a <font> tag in the <li> which seems to be interfering with the stylesheet. It is, however, creating the <li> and the <ul> in the light DOM as usual. [Example](http://codepen.io/nicolasmccurdy/pen/HnJCG)

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy yeah I just noticed this too when I was using the web inspector to see how the DOM changes with the new contentEditable content... any ideas on how to stop this new <font> tag? Or at least change use it to set the correct font?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like this is caused by a bug in WebKit-based browsers (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18427979/406249)). I tried Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, and the issue only appeared on Chrome and Firefox. Unfortunately, there is not much you can do besides not adding styles, waiting for a fix, or removing the extra HTML. If you would like to remove the extra HTML, you may find [Working around Chrome's contenteditable span bug](http://www.neotericdesign.com/blog/2013/3/working-around-chrome-s-contenteditable-span-bug) helpful.

Comment: Thanks @NicolasMcCurdy, that was perfect. If you post that as an answer then I'd be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like this is caused by a bug in WebKit-based browsers (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383803/browser-automatically-inserts-unwanted-code-on-enter-in-contenteditable-div/18427979#18427979)). I tried Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, and the issue only appeared on Chrome and Firefox. Unfortunately, there is not much you can do besides not adding styles, waiting for a fix, or removing the extra HTML. If you would like to remove the extra HTML, you may find [Working around Chrome's contenteditable span bug](http://www.neotericdesign.com/blog/2013/3/working-around-chrome-s-contenteditable-span-bug) helpful.

**Note:** This was copied from my comment.